# getting dictionary key by value

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine

I know there are multiple questions like this, but they dont solve my problem. Im very new and dont quite get me there.

My problem is that i want to get a whole Key and Value just from one Value.

My dictionary

```
    public Dictionary<string, (int Position, string Name, int Hp, int Power, int Agility)> Player1Inventory = new Dictionary<string, (int Position, string Name, int Hp, int Power, int Agility)>
{
    ["contentCube"] = (Position: 1, Name: "ContentCube", Hp: 200, Power: 100, Agility: 70),
};
```

And i need to get all the information based on his position. what ive found on other questions like this is to use Linq, but the examples they gave dont work for me.

Examples ive found and didnt work:

```
var myKey = types.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value == "one").Key;
```

and

```
var keysWithMatchingValues = dic.Where(p => p.Value == "a").Select(p => p.Key);
```

Any help or explanation is appreciated.

Comment: `x.Value.Name` ?

Comment: Your dictionary makes me feel pretty uncomfortable, as it's pretty hard to read and understand. I'd strongly suggest to create a class instead which holds your data - in particular when you have member-names in your code anyway.

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yeah it isnt easy to read, but im not very familiar with coding. The plan is to have a lot of Characters, and this works for me. i dont know how i would do that with classes(because im unfamiliar with it all).

Comment: @JustAHobbyGuyNoob for the performance it would be way better to have two dictionaries for going forth and back though! And then use a proper class instead of tuples

Comment: @derHugo Yeah i will need to look at classes more, but for now i have a sort of database/dictionary with all characters. then the game has 8 characters, 4 on each team where all the stats is loaded onto a PlayerScript on the characters itself where it holds public information like its health and so on. then i only use the dictionary once at the start of the game(i have no experience with performance balancing or programming, so i cant really be sure of what im doing is good) but yeah thanks for the advice! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost have it but you since Position is an int you can not compare it to a string without conversion first.
You can compare to the int value instead:

```
Dictionary<string, (int Position, string Name, int Hp, int Power, int Agility)> Player1Inventory = new Dictionary<string, (int Position, string Name, int Hp, int Power, int Agility)>
{
    ["contentCube"] = (Position: 1, Name: "ContentCube", Hp: 200, Power: 100, Agility: 70),
};
var myKey = Player1Inventory.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Position == 1).Key;

Console.WriteLine(myKey); // returns "contentCube"
```

Comment: Thank you A lot, this worked for me. every position is unique and i probobly dont need anything else than this. thank you again :)